# Recurrent Neural Networks for Time Series Prediction

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm new to Machine Learning, and I'm trying to implement on MATLAB a Neural Network in order to predict the next future closing price of a stock market security given past values of this security's closing price. Right now I'm lost with this, so I'm looking for some guidance from someone who knows more about Neural Networks than me.

So in order to do this prediction, I'm trying to use a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN). For this, I'm using MATLAB's native function `layrecnet`. The Inputs I am using to train the RNN are the daily closing prices on a given date range (01/01/2010 to 01/01/2015 for instance) and the Targets I'm using are the same as the inputs, but shifted one unit in time.

So for instance, if we have the inputs:

```
inputSeries = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.61 0.62]
```

Then the Targets I'm using are:

```
targetSeries = [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.61 0.62 0.63]
```

Everything is normalized from 0 to 1. This method makes sense in my head, since for a given sequence in the input, the network will have as a target the next value of that sequence. Although from the results I'm obtaining on test data, the network doesn't seem to predict anything; it just follows the same patterns observed on the test data.

I've been looking on how to implement an RNN to predict the next value of a sequence on MATLAB, although without finding anything that can guide me in the right path. Is the methodology I'm using totally wrong? Shouldn't I be using simple RNN's for this? Should I use another approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your methodology seems sound, and yes RNNs are appropriate for your data (a time series). However, there are a relatively small set of problems that are notoriously difficult to predict because they have chaotic behavior, and stock market predictions are one of them (the others include seizure prediction, earth quake prediction, hurricane prediction....). So, if you are asking because you are not getting good results, keep that in mind. Since you are using `MATLAB`, I would suggest looking `NARXNET` (nonlinear autoregressive neural network with external input,  https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/narxnet.html). These are like recurrent neural networks on steroids. You want to initially train in open loop form, and then retrain in closed loop form. Here is a helpful link that talks about open/closed loop forms:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/310535-narxnet-closed-loop-vs-open-loop. Hope this helps. Here is some code to get you started.

```
function a = myNARXNET(in, out)

X = tonndata(in,false,false);
T = tonndata(out,false,false);

trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation.

inputDelays = 1:2;
feedbackDelays = 1:2;
hiddenLayerSize = [10,10,10];

net = narxnet(inputDelays,feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize,'open',trainFcn);

net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'radbasn';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'mapminmax','mapstd'};
net.inputs{2}.processFcns = {'mapminmax','mapstd'};

[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,X,{},T);

net.trainParam.max_fail = 10;
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-10;

net.performParam.regularization = 0.5;

net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net.trainParam.min_grad = 1e-10;

net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'time';  % Divide up every sample

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean Squared Error

net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate', 'ploterrhist', ...
    'plotregression', 'plotresponse', 'ploterrcorr', 'plotinerrcorr'};

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t,xi,ai);
y = net(x,xi,ai);
e = gsubtract(t,y);
performance = perform(net,t,y);

%Switch the network to closed loop form and retrain
net = closeloop(net);
[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,X,{},T);
[net,t] = train(net,x,t,xi,ai);
y = net(x,xi,ai);
a = net;    

end
```